# Onclick function only displaying content for a second

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML goes like this

```
         <figure>
          <a href="">
            <div onmouseover="trash_display(event,this);" onmouseout="trash_out(event,this);"  class="roomandtrash">
                <img src="Iconos/bathroom2.png" alt="Bathroom" class="icon" >
                <img src="Iconos/tacho.png" alt="Trash"  class="trash_icon" onclick="display_box(event,this);">
            </div>  

            <div class="box">
                <h4 class="Messagebox">You are about to delete this room and all its devices. 
                </h4>
                <img src="Iconos/confirm.png" alt="Confirm" class="confirm">
                <img src="Iconos/cancel.png" alt="Cancel" class="cancel">
            </div>
          </a>
          <figcaption>Bathroom</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

When the user clicks on trash_icon the 'icon' class object and the 'trash_icon' object are supposed to disappear and then a square 'box' should appear. Something seems to be wrong as the box only appears for a second and then the icons mentioned above appear again.

Here's JS

```
function display_box(event, trash){

     var icon = trash.closest('div').querySelector('.icon');
     icon.style.display= "none";
     trash.visibility = "hidden";
     var box = trash.closest('a').querySelector('.box');
     box.style.display= "block";

}
```

Comment: Have you considered a side effect of your mouseover and mouseout events? May they hide the box again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. I added preventDefault to cancel the `<a>` event and tweaked the code a bit.

```
function display_box(event, trash){

event.preventDefault();

  var icon = trash.closest('div').querySelector('.icon');
             icon.style.display= "none";
             trash.style.display= "none";

  var box = trash.closest('a').querySelector('.box');
      box.style.display= "block";

}
```